# Stripe form not displaying errors, instead proper Ruby on Rails errors are shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Currently my code is not displaying errors in the form. When I submit the credit for declines, I get an actual proper Ruby on Rails error message. How do I get this error message to appear on the form?

Any ideas? Thanks!

subscriptions_controller.rb

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def new
        @subscription = Subscription.new
    end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

def subscription_params
    params.require(:subscription).permit(:stripe_card_token)
end


end
```

subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

    def save_with_payment
            customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
                :card => stripe_card_token,
                :description => "name",
                :plan => 121,
                :email => "email")

            self.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
            self.plan = 121
    end

end
```

subscriptions.js.coffee

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.

jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()

subscription =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_subscription').submit (e) ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      subscription.processCard()
      return false

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_subscription')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message) 
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
      false
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class='panel panel-default'>

    <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h2>Subscribe</h2>
    </div>

    <div class='panel-body'>

    <%= form_for @subscription, :html => {:class => 'main-form'} do |f| %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

        <div id='stripe_error' class="alert alert-info" style='display:none'>
        </div>


        <span class="help-block">Nothing is billed to your card for 7 days. <b>Guaranteed. </b>
            <br>If you choose to continue after 7 days, only then will you be billed.</span>

              <div class='form-group'>
                <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control input-box', :placeholder => 'Credit Card Number' %>
              </div>

        <div class='row'>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVC)" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control input-box', :placeholder => 'Security Code on Card (CVC)' %>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
                <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
                <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year+1, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
            </div>

        </div>



            <div>
                <%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: 'btn standard-button' %>
            </div>


        <% end %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I see a couple of potential issues:

Your save_with_payment message does not actually save your subscription model. You would need to actually call 'save' inside the save_with_payment method. This leads me to believe that **Stripe::Customer.create** is throwing an exception that is just getting bubbled up to your controller.

Assuming I am correct, then in order for you to actually get an error on the form you will need to trigger a validation error on your subscription model.

There are a number of ways you could approach this. A quick and dirty way might be to actually create the stripe customer in your custom validation itself. e.g.,

```
validate :can_create_stripe_customer, :if => :customer_id_is_nil_and_stripe_card_token_present?

def can_create_stripe_customer 
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :card => stripe_card_token,
            :description => "name",
            :plan => 121,
            :email => "email")

        self.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
        self.plan = 121
 rescue Exception > e
  errors.add(:base, e.message)
  false
end
```

This would give you the desired error on your model/form.  In your controller you would simply call

```
@subscription.save
```

Just an afterthought: 
if the code execution has gotten this far it's not clear to me that the user will be able to recover from the error because stripe has already validated that the user has provided a valid credit card by returning a token.